# Firefox 'Untrusted Connection' warning when logging in any site of StackExchange

Tags: support, login, firefox, ssl

When trying to enter https://stackexchange.com/users/login I get the 'This connection is untrusted' warning from Firefox. I'm currently using internet explorer to ask this question. I have no trouble in accessing https://stackexchange.com/ with Firefox, though.

In the details section:

> stackexchange.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it was signed using a signature algorithm that was disabled because that algorithm is not secure. (Error code: sec_error_cert_signature_algorithm_disabled)

If I try to add the exception, I still cannot access the page. Below is the info on the certificate exception I added.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at the certificate in the details dialog. What is the top certificate there?

Comment: @DeerHunter , I edited the question. Could you help me? thanks

Comment: Add Security Exception > View > Details > Certificate Hierarchy : what do you see there?

Comment: @DeerHunter new edit. ;)

Comment: I have similar issue in my pg too. Simply refreshing make it work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection is [MITMed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by your Avast! antivirus. You can disable that somewhere in Avast! options (like HTTPS filtering or Web/Mail Shield preferences).

Comment: But why is it that only today I get this error? I've had the avast! antivírus for quite some time now... And why only with firefox?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. - I don't know. Try disabling Web shield/HTTPS filtering and see how it goes. Avast! is a bit notorious for sending out details of your connections (IIRC).

Comment: which antivírus would you then recommend ?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. - You can keep Avast! but turn off the MITM thingie.

Comment: Should I be worried that they've hacked, or are allowing my pc docs/info to be hacked ?  I've just searched the web, and I'm getting a bit restless. =D

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. - Yes, that should probably be a concern.  I suggest asking on [Security.SE] about it.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Because Firefox started to show this message if SHA-1 certificates are used only on 1 January 2016. Other browsers probably don't block SHA-1 certificates yet, but as far as I know Chrome will start to do this soon as well.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Firefox itself, which does not yet support the [ChaCha20-Poly1305 cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) used by Stack Exchange SSL.

There is an open ticket in bugzilla about it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=917571

Comment: Srsly? Why does my connection go through ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES, though?

Comment: @DeerHunter no idea, I'm not that deep into the depths of SSL, just analyzed what I could see.